# What operators and functions can I use in a Views "Global: Math expression" field?

Tags: views, chaos-tool-suite

When you create a "Global: Math expression" field in Views, the following help appears beneath the Expression field:

> Enter mathematical expressions such as 2 + 2 or sqrt(5). You my assign variables and create mathematical functions and evaluate them. Use the ; to separate these. For example: f(x) = x + 2; f(2)

I tried to use a modulo operator (%), but it didn't work, and the function specified in that help is obviously not vanilla PHP.

What syntax or language is allowable in this field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Views Math expression fields use a custom expression parser in the Chaos Tool Suite (ctools) module. The code for this is contained in `ctools/includes/math-expr.inc`.

As of mid-July 2012, the built-in functions are:

```
'sin','sinh','arcsin','asin','arcsinh','asinh',
'cos','cosh','arccos','acos','arccosh','acosh',
'tan','tanh','arctan','atan','arctanh','atanh',
'pow', 'exp',
'sqrt','abs','ln','log',
'time', 'ceil', 'floor', 'min', 'max', 'round'
```

Most of these are PHP's own math functions. The trigonometric functions beginning with "arc" are aliases to the ones beginning with "a". "ln" is an alias for "log".

The built-in operators are `+` `-` `*` `/` `^`

The first four act just as they do in PHP. The fifth is the exponent operator; `x ^ y` is the same as `pow(x,y)`.

You can create your own functions using this syntax, and such functions can use more than one variable. You can use this to create your own modulo function:

```
mod(x,y) = x - (floor(x/y) * y);
```

(Beware: The above function does not work with negative numbers.)

Comment: If anyone can come up with a modulus function that *does* work in all cases, by all means edit my post. I'm sick of thinking about this problem after figuring all the rest of this crap out.

Comment: Couldn't you just wrap the `x` portion and `(floor(x/y) * y)` in `abs`? You would lose the sign but meh.

Comment: When I wrote that comment, I wasn't aware of the fact that there's disagreement among languages on how `x mod y` with negative `x` is even defined. So if my function above does something unexpected in that case, it will at least not be alone.